# How to make a material design spinner arise from a CardView

Tags: android, spinner, material-design

In Lollipop, when you tap on "When Calls and notifications arrive" under Sounds > Interruptions in the Settings app, a spinner with options emancipates right from that view.
How do you implement something like that, specifically in a `RelativeLayout` inside a `CardView`?

P.S : I am extremely new to Android/Java so browsing through the source code didn't help me much. Detailed help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's just a button that shows a Popup menu and not a spinner (because a spinner's drop-down matches its width with the spinner's width). Next, a flag in AppCompat library lets you show popups above an anchor view, but I'm unable to recall that flag.

Comment: Oh alright, used PopupMenu and it works well - just what I was looking for. I didn't need any anchor or anything, it hovers right on my TextView so that's fine by me. Thanks.

Comment: The flag for making it appear in front of your TextView is needed for < Lollipop :)